# Area of Paralleogram

Tags: geometry, area, quadrilateral

Why is the area of parallelogram not equal to the product of the distances between the two pairs of parallel sides? A parallelogram is just a rectangle that has a triangle cut off from one side and added to the other; so then why is the area not equal to the product of the distances between the two pairs of parallel sides?

Comment: No on the first because yes on the second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suggested, let's take a rectangle and cut a triangle from one side and add it to the other. Imagine the resulting parallelogram has two horizontal sides, and that the other two sides are "non-vertical" (else we'd still have a rectangle.) The distance between the two "non-vertical" sides would be measured **perpendicularly** to those sides; however the distance needed for the area would have to be measured horizontally, because that would have been the distance between those two sides when the shape was still a rectangle.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks @A.J.